# How to stream all data in spring-data repository?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to iterate all data in large mongodb collection, but existed method `findAll()` feteches all data to memory before data will be returned.

I tried to make next method:

```java
    Stream<ContentIdentity> findAllAndStream();
```

but got exception:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type ContentIdentity!

next method works fine

```java
    @Query("{}")
    Stream<ContentIdentity> findAllByCustomQueryAndStream();
```

but it looks like a crutch in code

How to do I make it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
Stream<ContentIdentity> stream = StreamUtils.createStreamFromIterator(
    mongoTemplate.stream(new Query(), ContentIdentity.class));
```